# All combinations to a substitution cipher

Tags: substitution-cipher

Is there any software that can output all possible solutions to a substitution cipher?
I have a 34 character substitution cipher as follows:
ABHIJCKDELMFNOEPQ
RDSTUVWGFADBXCYGZ

15 of the characters in the cipher are repeated.
I would like a software to output all possible word combinations that will fit the cipher (English words only).
I know there will be thousands, maybe millions, of possibilities but I need to evaluate each possibility.

Do you know of such a software?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is more about [software-recommendations.se] than a cryptographic question; simply asking for libraries or resources is considered off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Another name for a substitution cipher is a cryptogram, which are popular recreational puzzles.  There are several on-line cryptogram solvers.  Here are two that do what you ask:

- https://www.boxentriq.com/code-breaking/cryptogram
- https://www.quipqiup.com/

If you wanted to write your own software to analyze the ciphertext, then you just need a word-list.  For each word in the word-list, you create and store a canonical encoding:  e.g. "people" becomes "abcadb".  To determine if the first word of plaintext could be "people", you can then apply the same encoding to the first six letters of ciphertext and then compare.

---

Note that the example ciphertext provided has some unusual structure.  It may not be a pure substitution cipher:

```
ABHIJCKDELMFNOEPQ RDSTUVWGFADBXCYGZ
..HIJ.K..LM.NO.PQ R.STUVW.....X.Y.Z
```